# How to run Ubuntu and windows 10 on external hard drive with Virtualbox

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a Macbook pro and a 4TB external Hard drive. Now I  want to use ubuntu and windows10 running on the external hard drive in a manner where I get 3 TB for random storage purposes and 500 GB for Linux and 500 GB.So I want to know whether I can use a single hard drive to load BOTH windows 10 and ubuntu and still 3TB more space for my use... do I have to partition the hard drive into three different parts.. I need to use virtual box where windows and ubuntu are running on the external drive and I should be able to use the remaining space..thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to partition the external HD at all. Virtualbox wants use it's own virtual drive files on whatever filesystem the HD has.

Comment: Your question has a lot of ambiguity in it. You may wish to review it with "readers eyes" and then make some minor edits. You want to run Virtualbox to run a Windows guest OS, and a Ubuntu guest OS, yes? Know that VB creates a folder in your /home/username called `Virtualbox VM's`, and it contains the VDI disk images of your guest OS's. I don't know if VB will let you easily relocate that folder or its VDI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualbox actually doesn't need a specific file system that you need to format your external HDD. You can just format it as Ubuntu may read the HDD and then simply create a new space on external HDD using Virtualbox's application.

**EDIT**:

You may format your HDD to HFS, because FAT filesystem has a max space support about 4 GB. You can't store 500 GB virtual disk on this filesystem. However on HFS you can store since it supports large amount of size.

Comment: so I just set the same  HDD for both windows and ubuntu in the virtual box without needing to partition the drive......and if I do this I will only be able to use ubuntu and windows in the virtual box if I connect the hard disk.

Comment: Virtualbox creates virtual files on your external HDD. It doesn't create a partition, so you could your External HDD also as f.e a backup machine.

Comment: so .... the virtualbox will work in its own file system inside the HDD and I can keep using the same HDD for different purposes as well?

Comment: @HELLDOZER That was what I'm trying to say.

Comment: cool man thanks a bunch....that is what I have been trying to understand..... I did not know whether I should partition the drive or anything like that..... I appreciate you sharing ur time and knowledge :-)

Comment: @HELLDOZER Only problem I see is that your external HDD should not be formatted as FAT because it has a limitation that you can only give 4 GB space to vdi on FAT formatted device. If you format HDD to HFS then you can arrange the space about 500 GB.

Comment: hey ....today just to try it out I partitioned 100 gb from a 500 gig hdd and then I installed DSL using a virtualdisk image which I had linked to the 100gig partition and then also install puppy linux using virtual hard disk that also linked to that same 100 gig partition ...... now when i went into the partition it showed that it had a VDI file and VHD file..... and i also moved the iso files to the same 100 gig partition..... now the interesting this was both of the OSs ran smoothly .....

Comment: ......I got curious as to what would happen if I remove the external HDD.... i thought it would show some error or freeze up or something like that...to my surprize it was still working so I opened up the terminals on both the OSs and both of them were working fine....this brings me to the question .....now the VHD and VDI files are in the disconnected HDD along with the iso files.....now where is virtual box reading and writing from?

Comment: @HELLDOZER your hole hard disk is the .vdi file. It goes up as you're using and it is shut down when you're not using it. If you delete the file then Virtualbox can not boot your virtual OS. Also the support files that reads your .vdi files are stored under /home/username/Virtualbox VM's.